# How do we deal with idea generation questions?

Tags: discussion, questions, close-reasons

As we know and will likely keep seeing as this site progresses there will be plenty of subjectivity. I anticipate that we are going to get questions along the lines of

- What can I do with [x]
- I just started using [x] and I'm addicted. What else can I do with it?
- What cool stuff can I do with toilet paper tubes?

Can't think of other possibilities just yet. People are going to ask us what they should do with something or what they could be capable of doing.

How should we approach these sort of questions ?

Answer (score 9):

## Vote to close as too opinion based or too broad

These should pretty much just be closed outright. Somethin that is this open-ended cannot possibly be answered without either a bias -or- there would be endless possible solutions.

However if the OP of the question was to try and make the question more specific like:

- What can I do with [x] to make it work with [y] using [z] tools

True, that could still be open ended but **if you (the OP) can at least try add more specifications to the question** then the options would narrow down to where we could constructively answer these.

Comment: Yes, these are generally bad fits for this site. This is the equivalent to the ban of "What can I do with _____ ingredient?" on [cooking.se].

Comment: Keep in mind that there's nothing *inherently* wrong with someone asking for suggestions, so in closing these posts, be sure to **include a good dose of *thoughtful* guidance** that such questions are simply not a good fit for ***this*** type of Q&A.  We're the odd man out here; there may come a time where we can better support these "poll the community" questions, but of the time being, they tend to become problematic, so it is advisable (as said here) to forgo them completely.

Comment: @RobertCartaino We do want to see them to get an idea of what people are asking for. Also people can still ask and there can always be room for improvement. Like you said, this can always be revisited later. I hope that will will guide more that block and deter

Answer (score 3):

Yes in general a 'What can I do with x?' is really 'What is your opinion of things I can do, give me some ideas'  This is usually too broad and almost always opinion based.  The good news is many of them can be narrowed down and fixed.