# On-topic FAQ Draft

Tags: discussion, on-topic

Thank you for all the suggestions from [What should our on-topic FAQ contain?](https://crafts.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/167/what-should-our-on-topic-faq-contain)

The pro tem mods have discussed and compiled the ideas into the following text to go on the [What questions can I ask about here?](https://crafts.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) page.

*This list is not carved in stone; if we later realize we need to add or remove something, that can be done.*

> We welcome specific questions about a variety of arts and crafts.
>   These topics are welcome on our site:
>
> - Tool usage, upkeep and selection
> - Material selection and usage
> - Asking for clarification of a specific tutorial step ("why isn't this working?" or "what do these instructions mean?")
> - Attributes of different media and how they interact
> - Proper media storage and final product preservation
>
> The following subjects are considered off-topic for our site:
>
> - Asking for inspiration ("What craft can I do with ...?")
> - Broad questions like "where do I start", or requesting a tutorial for a larger project
> - Discussion or critique of works, whether your own another artist's
> - Product and service recommendations ("Where can I get (product)?" or "Where can I find someone that does (service) in (area)?")
>
> Other arts, such as [photography](https://photo.stackexchange.com/), [graphic arts](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/), and
>   performing arts like dance and the dramatic arts are not on topic for
>   Arts & Crafts.

Comment: I only just saw this now _Discussion or critique of works, whether your own another artist's_ should be _Discussion or critique of works, whether your own __or__ another artist's_

Comment: I'm struggling to phrase it appropriately, but I've noticed that there are a number of questions that are really more about general DIY than art. Seems as though the use of the term "paint" is sufficient to get by, but I'm not really sold on that. Most recent example is [Expedite drying acrylic painting in a cold temperature environment](http://crafts.stackexchange.com/questions/1872/expedite-drying-acrylic-painting-in-a-cold-temperature-environment), but there's been a few. I was on the fence before, but less so now...

Comment: When might this get added to the page? I just went there to check something but it is still empty :(

Comment: @whrrgarbl That's actually a good independent meta question, and I'd encourage you to ask it instead of simply commenting.

Comment: @Erica [Done!](http://meta.crafts.stackexchange.com/questions/274/when-will-the-on-topic-faq-go-live)

Answer (score 2):

I like it but think we could add the relevant meta discussions to our off-topic points.

[DIY.SE does this with a couple of their bullets as well](https://diy.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)

[as does Photo.SE](https://photo.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)

> We welcome specific questions about a variety of arts and crafts.
>   These topics are welcome on our site:
>
> - Tool usage, upkeep and selection
> - Material selection and usage
> - Asking for clarification of a specific tutorial step ("why isn't this working?" or "what do these instructions mean?")
> - Attributes of different media and how they interact
> - Proper media storage and final product preservation
>
> The following subjects are considered off-topic for our site:
>
> - [Asking for inspiration](https://crafts.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43/how-do-we-deal-with-idea-generation-questions/44#44) ("What craft can I do with ...?")
> - Broad questions like "where do I start", or [requesting a tutorial for a larger project](https://crafts.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/216/are-how-do-i-reproduce-this-questions-on-topic?cb=1)
> - Discussion or critique of works, whether your own another artist's
> - Product and service recommendations ("Where can I get (product)?" or "Where can I find someone that does (service) in (area)?")
>
> Other arts, such as [photography](https://photo.stackexchange.com/), [graphic arts](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/), and
>   performing arts like dance and the dramatic arts are not on topic for
>   Arts & Crafts.

There are others but this should get my point across. I wanted to add this one but I don't think it makes the product and service recommendation clear as off topic. If I am wrong it should be added as well.

[Questions asking for resources - On or off topic?](https://crafts.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/183/questions-asking-for-resources-on-or-off-topic)

Comment: Related we should make a meta about Critique  in case that comes up again.

Comment: I think it's a bit messy to have a few random links but not have links for everything. I would prefer to have a single statement at the bottom that says something like "For more information on this topic, please see _____" And that links to the bigger discussion thread that should have all of the individual links.

Comment: If we wanted to fill the rest that would be easy with a couple of meta q's. The on topics don't need anything

Comment: I think it is important to provide users the least amount of clicks to get to the relevant information. If the do manage to read the FAQ they would be one click away from the information they need. Instead of one more to the meta to then find the next relevant post (Depending on what you were envisioning for this). I don't want a signpost to another signpost. Am I making sense?

Comment: The issue with direct links to meta questions is that sometimes the "answer" is not necessarily in a single thread, but linking to a single question may give that illusion. Reading meta in general, and finding the topics, gives users a better idea about the broad voice of the community.

Comment: @CreationEdge in that case we can create a dedicated thread where there is one answer which explains the situation properly w.r.t each topic.

Answer (score 0):

> The following subjects are considered off-topic for our site:
>
> - ..
> - Discussion or critique of works, whether your own another artist's
> - ..

I think we should follow the **photo.se** site's rules on this one.

https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2039/can-we-re-open-the-door-to-something-a-little-like-photo-critique

This question of mine is welcomed there: 
https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/77726/how-to-improve-the-composition-of-the-scene-depicting-times-effect-on-age

Just look at the composition tag there:
https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/composition?sort=votes&pageSize=50

**Only difference is that they use camera and we use our hands.**

I suggest that we add the clarification link to the faq like photo.se have done here: https://photo.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

That link can be a dedicated thread to explain that point in a single answer.

Comment: This has been brought up before and I want to clarify what the intent of that was. _Discussion or critique of works, whether your own another artist's_ was meant to cover "What do you think of this?" type questions that would be too open ended or opinionated. However asking how to replicate or improve on certain specific techniques can make the basis of good questions as it is narrowed to a specific topic.

Comment: Which thread?  Point out please.  @Matt

Comment: I think there was a chat thread but this also exists: http://meta.crafts.stackexchange.com/a/224/44

Comment: In that case, I suggest add the clarification to the faq like photo.se have done. @matt

Comment: Like this http://photo.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic @matt

Comment: Have you seen the other answer in this question? That is exactly what I am asking to do

Comment: The answer does not have a link for this particular point. @Matt.  So I wrote this answer to emphasise this point.

Comment: This answer is not about the FAQ draft but a discussion on one of its points. If this was a separate meta then, once the proper discussion is complete, then we potentially could add the link into the FAQ draft I am proposing.

Comment: Why is the down vote here? @Matt  can you guess?

Comment: Not sure beyond what I have already said.

Comment: I think this is a useful point, and the existing phrasing could be interpreted as overly broad. I'll make a separate meta question to help out with that. (I feel it is helpful to have a full Question, especially for issues that will affect policy long-term, instead of a handful of answers with comment-based discussion)

Comment: @Erica thanks for reading it throughly, and then judging it.